# Stripe - single-use cards and delayed charge

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

Our site currently asks customers to provide their CC data every time they put an order. Few days later we charge the card, very often with a different amount than shown during the checkout because of merging orders, changing shipment method and so on.

We'd like to migrate to Stripe, but we'd like not to change the current behaviour. Few questions arose while we read the Stripe docs:

1) Stripe.js allows to create a Source without a customer. This seems ideal for us, but the following text from Stripe docs caught our attention:

> A card source must be used within a few minutes of its creation as CVC
>   information is only available for a short amount of time. Card sources
>   do not expire, but using them after a delay can result in a charge
>   request that is performed without CVC information. The consequences of
>   this can be higher decline rates and increased risk of fraud.

So we shouldn't charge the Source few days later? If so, isn't it also a problem for Sources attached to customers, because their CVCs are forgotten as well?

2) To keep things simple, we'd prefer to avoid creating customers and managing their sources in Stripe. Stripe has the concept of single-use sources, that can be charged without attaching them to customers, but the docs say that the amount is required when they are created. We don't know the exact amount at the checkout process, so could we put a bigger number as an upper limit of what we'll charge in the future and provide the exact amount during charging the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're correct, the CVC is lost anyway but this is not the point that Stripe is trying to make. When you attach the Source to a customer, Stripe will run a $0 or $1 authorization on the card with the bank to make sure it's valid. This lets them catch expired or invalid cards immediately. This also lets them send the CVC to the bank, since they have it at that point, to catch invalid CVC which is important to combat fraud.

If you were to create a Source and not charge it for a few days, that would technically work. The risk is that when you do charge it, the bank won't see the CVC and won't be able to tell you if it was correct or not, increasing the risk of fraud.

To avoid this, Stripe recommends that you save the Source on a Customer. This is just one extra API request which lets you catch invalid cards immediately. Then, days later, when you create the charge on that customer/source, the bank might still decline it (insufficient funds for example) but you would decrease the risk of charging a bad card and catch issues immediately on tokenization. It's better for you as a business but also better for the customer in case they mistyped their CVC or expiration date, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there's another way of triggering the $0/$1 authorization other than associating a card with a customer?

Comment: No there isn't, that's controlled by Stripe and not something you can decide on your end.